# IntelliJ IDEA grails 3 Domain class no save method

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-orm, intellij-14, intellij-15

i am new to grails . i installed grails 3.1.8 and JDEA 2016.1 ultimate .
in grails project  JDEA **can not resolve save method** for domain class objects and also read, delete, get. **BUT it works** and data is saved in database. so , how to solve this problem?
thank you!
sorry for bad English!

Comment: When you say "not resolve save method", are you meaning that Intellij does not have intellisense? If I am right, as far as I know, you can't. IDE's (GGTS, Intellij, Eclipse, etc) are not fully compatible yet with grails 3.x

Comment: idea says: "cannot resolve symbol save", i do not know what is intellisense, but it look like that there is no save method, but in runtime it works and data save in database.

Comment: Intellisense is the microsoft implementation, but [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion) you have the definition. As I said, probably because IntelliJ is not fully compatible with grails 3.x, idea doesn't know about the method but it works because the method exists in grails domain classes